# How do you write a stored procedure that will either update or insert into a table using another table as the source

Tags: azure, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL database via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will take records from a staging table and either use those record to update or insert into a Target table (T).

This is the stored procedure that I have written:

```
/*** Create (or Re-create( the procedure ***/
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PostCreateJockeyMerge]
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
MERGE dbo.JOCKEY AS T
USING dbo.jockey_tmp AS S
ON T.JOCKEY_TF LIKE S.JOCKEY_TF
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.FIRST_NAME = IsNULL(S.FIRST_NAME,T.FIRST_NAME),
           T.MIDDLE_NAME = IsNULL(S.MIDDLE_NAME, T.MIDDLE_NAME),
           T.LAST_NAME =  IsNULL(S.LAST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME),
           T.JOCKEY_NAME =  IsNULL(S.JOCKEY_NAME, T.JOCKEY_NAME),
           T.JOCKEY_INITIALS =  IsNULL(S.JOCKEY_INITIALS, T.JOCKEY_INITIALS),
           T.JOCKEY_KEY =  IsNULL(S.JOCKEY_KEY, T.JOCKEY_KEY),
           T.JOCKEY_RAGS =  IsNULL(S.JOCKEY_RAGS, T.JOCKEY_RAGS)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (JOCKEY_TF, LAST_NAME) VALUES(JOCKEY_TF, LAST_NAME);
END
```

When I run the procedure I receive the Command(s) completed successfully, however, upon further inspection no records have been inserted into the Target table. For example, before I run the stored procedure the S source table (jockey_tmp) has 550 unique records and the target table has 300 unique records.  After I run the stored procedure the target table still has the same unique record - I've written a stored procedure that does nothing.

I researched this online and believe this should be working. Does anyone have any insights to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I suggest first using output to cofirm that you aren't inserting records: http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/05/writing-t-sql-merge-statements-the-right-way/

Comment: I know you already said there were unique records, but just to be sure can you post the results of `select count(*) rc, count(distinct jockey_tf) uc from jockey_tmp` (and also for `jockey`)

Comment: I have confirmed that I am not inserting records.

Comment: Sure, For Jockey RC and UC were both 387. For jockey_tmp RC was 524 and UC 490.

Comment: So JOCKEY_TF is not unique in staging. And I just noticed you're using `LIKE` not equals. What does this query return: `select * from dbo.jockey_tmp S where not exists (select * from dbo.JOCKEY T where T.JOCKEY_TF LIKE S.JOCKEY_TF)`. If it returns no rows then I suggest you go through your data and identify one row that you think should be inserted and post it up.

Comment: It returned 337 rows.  Should I be using = instead of Like.

Comment: If that query returned 336 rows then that's how many it should be inserting so I'm not sure why it isn't. I don't know the nature of your data at a guess you should be using `=` not `LIKE`. Please edit your question and post some sample data from both tables for starters.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!